# How to plot multiple images from file in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot multiple images from a file in jupyter notebook. The images are displayed, but they are in one column. I'm using:

```
%matplotlib inline
from os import listdir
form PIL import image as PImage
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def loadImages(path):
    imagesList = listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        img = PImage.open(path+image)
        LoadedImages.append(img)
        Return loadedImages
path = 'C:/Users/Asus-PC/flowers/'
imgs = loadImages(path)

for img in imgs
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(img)
```

I would like them to appear in a grid layout (row and column). Part of the problem is that I do not know what the arguments to add_subplot mean. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check out [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html). I find this to be one of the easiest ways. There are quite a few posts on this I'm sure. Here's [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42818501/6942527) that I posted previously.

Comment: You don't need to import PIL, matplotlib has `plt.imread`.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with `matplotlib` but it tends to be really slow and inefficient for displaying big number of images. So if you want to do it much faster and easier - I would recommend using my package called [IPyPlot](https://github.com/karolzak/ipyplot):

```
import ipyplot

ipyplot.plot_images(images_list, max_images=20, img_width=150)
```

It supports images in following formats:
- `string` file paths
- `PIL.Image` objects
- `numpy.ndarray` objects representing images

And it's capable of displaying hundreds of images in just ~70ms

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiplesubplots using `plt.subplots`. Determine the number of columns and rows on the number of loaded images. Something like:

```
from os import listdir
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = 'C:/Users/Asus-PC/flowers/'
imagesList = listdir(path)
n_images = len(imagesList)    

figure, axes = plt.subplots(n_images, 1)   # (columns, rows)    
for ax, imgname in zip(axes, imagesList):  # Iterate over images and
        img = plt.imread(path+imgname)     # axes to plot one image on each.
        ax.imshow(img)                     # You can append them to an empty
                                           # list if you need them later.
plt.show()
```