# how to plot graphs for dataframe side by side?

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, boxplot

I want to plot multiple graphs for Dataframes and box plots side by side instead of top to bottom.
For example,
If i plot these 3 graphs in will appear top to bottom.I want to display it sides by side(left to right)

```
df.plot(x="Date", y=["Temp.PM", "Temp.AM"],subplots=True )
df.plot(x="Date", y=["pH_AM", "pH_PM"])
df.plot(x="Date", y=["WindSpeed_AM", "WindSpeed_PM"])
```

[image]
Rather than appearing this way.

Comment: plt.subplots is your friend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42818361/how-to-make-two-plots-side-by-side-using-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make two plots side-by-side using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42818361/how-to-make-two-plots-side-by-side-using-python)

Comment: As Ruthger suggested, look into subplots.

Answer (score 1):

The following serves as an example. There are of course many parameters that can be set and changed:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Some example data:

```
x1 = np.random.rand(10) * 10
x2 = np.random.rand(10) * 20
x3 = np.random.rand(10) * 30
```

Creating the subplots:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3)
axes[0].boxplot(x1)
axes[1].boxplot(x2)
axes[2].boxplot(x3)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Of course, different type of plots (boxplots, lineplots etc) can be combined.

Comment: How would you combine/plot the three boxplots of varying lengths in one frame?