# Combine several Matplotlib figures into one

Tags: python, matplotlib

Assume a library function that creates a figure internally:

```
def plot_data(data):  # cannot change this implementation
   ...
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(w, h))
   ax.plot(...)
   ...
   return fig, ax
```

I create two plots using the above function:

```
fig1, ax1 = plot_data(data1)
fig2, ax2 = plot_data(data2)
```

How can I put these two plots/figures side by side? A naive approach is as follows (does not work this way):

```
fig0, ax0 = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(w, h))
ax0[0] = ax1
ax0[1] = ax2
plt.close(fig1)
plt.close(fig2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you check [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42818361/how-to-make-two-plots-side-by-side-using-python

Comment: subplots creates new axes, the question is how to combine existing ones

Comment: Thats not really possible.  Preferable is that the function does not create the figure or axes, but rather acts on an existing axes.

Comment: You might interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46906599/10315163), but why bother that. Just change `plot_data(data)` to `plot_data(ax, data)` would make life much more easier.

Comment: plot_data is a library function that cannot be changed @Ynjxsjmh