# What's the best way to visualize link attacks in 3D

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx, graph-visualization, pyvis

This is a follow up to my previous question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63716243/whats-the-best-way-to-visualize-link-attacks) to visualize edge attacks in graphs.

The code below has been posted as an [answer to my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63862841/8281509)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

H = nx.gnm_random_graph(n=8, m=9, seed=5)  # generate a random graph
H.add_edges_from([('I', 1), (5, 'O')])  # adding input/output nodes
pos = nx.spring_layout(H, iterations=200)  # find good positions for nodes


def attack(G, edge, color):
    G.remove_edge(*edge)  # first remove the edge

    # check if another could be also impacted
    if G.degree[edge[0]] == 1:
        neighbor = [n for n in G.neighbors(edge[0])][0]
        impacted_edge = (edge[0], neighbor)

    elif G.degree[edge[1]] == 1:
        neighbor = [n for n in G.neighbors(edge[1])][0]
        impacted_edge = (edge[1], neighbor)

    else:
        impacted_edge = None

    G.add_edge(*edge)  # put back the edge to redraw it

    # redraw the attacked edge (solid) and the possible impacted one (dashed)
    if impacted_edge:
        nx.draw_networkx_edges(
            G,
            edgelist=[impacted_edge],
            pos=pos,
            edge_color=color,
            style='dashed',
            width=4
        )
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(
        G,
        edgelist=[edge],
        pos=pos,
        edge_color=color,
        label=f'attack {edge[0]}{edge[1]}',
        style='solid',
        width=4
    )


# attack some edges
attack(H, (6, 4), color='red')
attack(H, (3, 6), color='blue')
attack(H, (1, 2), color='green')

nx.draw(H, pos, node_size=700, with_labels=True, node_color='gray')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The solid lines indicate the edges that are attacked and the dashed lines of same color indicate the neighboring edges that are impacted due to a specific attack.

The answer helps but there is a problem when the impacted edges overlap.

Example,

```
 attack(H, (6, 4), color='red')
 attack(H, (5, 4), color='yellow')
```

[image]

The colors overlap and it's hard to visualize. If we can draw the dashed lines that indicate the impacted/attacked edges next to each other, without overlapping like shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHiFi.png) that will be good.

Suggestions on how to improve this visualization will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: The answer posted below is really useful for 2D networks and I am still
looking for ways to extend this to visualize 3D networks (i.e when x,y,z coordinates are available as `pos` attributes of a node) in pyvis. Suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the title of your question doesn't reflect the problem and it makes it look like a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Another good way to avoid the overlapping edges in your graph is to use `pyvis`, however the problem here is that it only supports parallel edges in directed graphs. One solution is to visualize your graph as a directed one and then tweak the edge options to make the arrow unnoticeable. Add the following snippet to end of the above code.

```py
from pyvis.network import Network


N = Network(bgcolor='#222222', font_color='white', directed=True)
N.set_edge_smooth('dynamic')

for n in H.nodes:
    N.add_node(n, color='gray')

for e in H.edges:
    N.add_edge(e[0], e[1], color='gray', width=0)

for e in impacted_edges:
    N.add_edge(e[0], e[1], color=e[2], width=1, dashes=True)

for e in edges:
    N.add_edge(e[0], e[1], color=e[2], width=1)

N.set_options('''
var options = {
  "edges": {
    "arrows": {
      "to": {
        "enabled": true,
        "scaleFactor": 0
      },
      "middle": {
        "enabled": true,
        "scaleFactor": 0
      },
      "from": {
        "enabled": true,
        "scaleFactor": 0
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "inherit": true
    },
    "smooth": {
      "forceDirection": "none"
    }
  },
  "physics": {
    "minVelocity": 0.75
  }
}
''')

N.write_html('example_graph.html')
```

You can find the following graph in `example_graph.html`:
[image]

Comment: May I know if pyvis can be used for generating 3D graphs? Or in other words, I'd like to know how the positions of H.Nodes can be added to the pyvis graph `N`

Comment: Hi @Azim Mazinani I also tried  `N.show('edge_attack.html')
    N.show_buttons()`  in place of `N.write_html('example_graph.html')` but it shows an error ` self.options.configure = Configure(enabled=True, filter_=filter_)        
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'configure'`. Could you please suggest what's going wrong here?